# Salesforce: Which API to use without Login required?

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, salesforce

I'm currently working on a native Android app for my company and ran into some problems with Salesforce lately.

I hope I can find some help here.

**What I want to achieve:**
The company has a lot of Accounts in Salesforce with 3 important fields for the app: Name, Business (Workshop or Parts Dealer) and location(latitude, longitude)
I would like to show those Accounts(Workshops/Parts Dealers) as markers on a google map in my Android app based on a radius around the user's current location. So it would be more than sufficient to get the data as JSON or XML(i read about sObjects, which would be nice too)

The app will be freely available on Google Play Store and every user should be able to see all the Workshops/Parts dealers around the world.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't find a way to fetch the data inside my app without authenticating every user with a Salesforce-Login. 
Which API is the best to use in this case?

It would be so awesome if anybody could help me with this problem.

**What I tried so far:** 
- SalesforceMobileSDK: If i extend `SalesForceApplication()` i always end up with the Salesforce-Login Screen.
It seems that every client has to be authenticated for API-calls to work. I tried using the method `peekUnauthenticatedRestClient()`, but this method only works on full path URL's(e.g. "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=James%20Brown&type=artist"), which isn't really practical for my Use-case.

- I feel like I read nearly all docs about salesforce API, but can't quite get my head around how to solve this problem, although it seems like to be a pretty common use-case.
- would a salesforce-apex method which would select all records inside a set radius around the user's location to be accessible without authentication?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Roman

Comment: @Puja please don't do aggressive edits for a language / platform you don't know much about. It's `sObjects`, not "subjects". Not a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try asking on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/). Your question is more about licensing model than a particular programming problem. It might even be the case that you don't really need Salesforce for your project, you'd be better off on Heroku (even free tier) if the login piece is an issue...

All Salesforce APIs require some form of authentication. If you're positive you don't want to hardcode "Integration user" credentials in the app and you don't want to pay for (self-)registered user licenses in your org...

Try to read about these:

[Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites) - piece of Visualforce running under specific "guest user", letting you view & interact with SF data without having to log in. You expose SF data to the world but that means it's your job to handle security (if any) and craft the API. You want to really display the data to human? Or just return JSON content or what...

Sites are meant to be displayin some incentive to contact you. Your product catalog / basic order form. Some map of nearby locations. Maybe a "contact us" form. There's limit on the traffic so eventually they'll explode as your app gets popular:

[image]

[Customer Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_about_hvpu.htm&type=5) - typically you need named licenses (even if they're fairly cheap) to let your customers log in to your SF. You create a Contact, click magic button - boom, this Contact now has a real matching User record with its own license. Think of it as some kind of step up from Sites - it'll still have some limits but will offer more than just raw API access and you'll have better control on what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. I ended up using Apex REST